# Cast/Convert Arithmetic Overflow Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, overflow

This works

```
select top(1786519) CONVERT(Decimal(8,2), Cost) 
from table
```

This does not

```
select top(1786520) CONVERT(Decimal(8,2), Cost) 
from table
```

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
> Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric.

Is there significance in this many rows that causes the overflow error?

Comment: You must have a value in row 1786520 which doesn't convert as per the error. Show us the original value as stored in the table.

Comment: The fact you don't have an `ORDER BY` means that you might even get the error with a `TOP(1)` as the row(s) returned is *completely* arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

You could use *try_convert* to find which row(s) contain data that cannot cast to the target data type, for example,

```
with x as (
  select Convert(float, 123456.78) cost union all
  select Convert(float, 1234567.789)  /* too large for decimal (8,2) */
)
select *
from x
where try_convert(Decimal(8,2), Cost) is null;
```

Comment: Sadly, we are currently stuck on SQL 2008 R2 --  no try_cast or try_convert.

Comment: I've amended the TAGs on your question to reflect this. No doubt (yet) another reason you have to upgrade to a supported version ;) Have you tried just selecting from your table where cost > 999999.99?

Comment: Thank you! First Post on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

`FLOAT` in SQL is painful to work with converting to `VARCHAR` and measuring the length won't work correctly. Since you don't have `TRY_CAST`, you have to "guess" if SQL can convert it. I think by converting to a larger decimal and checking the length, you should be able to identify the numbers that don't fit into your `DECIMAL(8,2)`

Identify `FLOAT` that cannot fit into decimal for SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
SELECT Cost
FROM YourTable
WHERE LEN(CAST(Cost AS decimal(38, 2))) > 9 /*More than 8 digits + 1 character for period*/
```